# Decompress Zlib data

Tags: c#, c++, matlab, c#-4.0, zlib

I'm currently trying to decompress some bytes from .mat file compressed by `Zlib`.
I read paragraph 3, page 1-12 from [MAT-File Format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf), it told that the bytes in `.mat` file is compressed by `Zlib`.

So, my question is, does C# have some APIs or libraries that can decompress the bytes.
If I got a group of bytes like

```
6236 20e6 0062 1606 0860 85f2 1981 980b
4cb3 30e4 25e6 a60a 40f9 2545 9989 39f1
```

Then I load them into an SByte array, how could I decompress them?

I also checked some libraries online. It seems that what they can do is to decompress the whole file, instead of some bytes....

I am quite new about this respect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `InflaterInputStream` from [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). `.mat` file has header with 0x88 length, so you have to skip it. I took sample file from here [SampleMatlabMatDataFiles.zip](https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/downloads/detail?name=SampleMatlabMatDataFiles.zip).

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("c.mat").Skip(0x88).ToArray();
byte[] decompressedData = new byte[10000];
int decompressedLength = 0;
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(data))
using (InflaterInputStream inflater = new InflaterInputStream(memory))
    decompressedLength = inflater.Read(decompressedData, 0, decompressedData.Length);
```